# Why isn't LaTeX centering with the geometry package in use

Tags: horizontal-alignment, geometry

I am messing around with LaTeX and I am trying to center a title at the top of a legal sized sheet of paper with margins at .25 inch.   I can't get the title to center with a center environment `\centering` or `\centerline`.   If I remove the `geometry` package, the output is as expected.   What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[10pt,legalpaper]{report}

\usepackage[margin=.25in,text={8in,13.5in},centering]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
ARIZONA PRELIMINARY TWENTY DAY NOTICE \newline 
IN ACCORDANCE WITH ARIZONA REVISED STATUTES SECTION 33-992.01  \newline
THIS IS NOT A LIEN AND IS NOT A REFLECTION ON THE INTEGRITY OF ANY CONTRACTOR OR          SUBCONTRACTOR 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to specify `margin=.25in`: just the `text` dimensions and `centering` suffice to set the parameters.

Answer (score 5):

Your use of `\newline` is messing the paragraph alignment up. Here's a different way of looking at it using paragraph breaks (`\par`, via `\\`), or by setting it in a centered [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=.25in,paper=legalpaper]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  ARIZONA PRELIMINARY TWENTY DAY NOTICE \newline 
  IN ACCORDANCE WITH ARIZONA REVISED STATUTES SECTION 33-992.01  \newline
  THIS IS NOT A LIEN AND IS NOT A REFLECTION ON THE INTEGRITY 
    OF ANY CONTRACTOR OR SUBCONTRACTOR 
\end{center}

\begin{center}
  ARIZONA PRELIMINARY TWENTY DAY NOTICE \\
  IN ACCORDANCE WITH ARIZONA REVISED STATUTES SECTION 33-992.01 \\
  THIS IS NOT A LIEN AND IS NOT A REFLECTION ON THE INTEGRITY 
    OF ANY CONTRACTOR OR SUBCONTRACTOR 
\end{center}

\noindent
{\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X}
  ARIZONA PRELIMINARY TWENTY DAY NOTICE \\
  IN ACCORDANCE WITH ARIZONA REVISED STATUTES SECTION 33-992.01 \\
  THIS IS NOT A LIEN AND IS NOT A REFLECTION ON THE INTEGRITY 
    OF ANY CONTRACTOR OR SUBCONTRACTOR 
\end{tabularx}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `\\` instead of `\newline` in environment `center`. `\\` is redefined, it ends the paragraph, but removes `\parskip`. `\newline` keeps the original meaning. It ends a line in the usual justified paragraphs. A forced line break needs to fill the current line and `\newline` adds `\hfil`. This messes up the centering of the first two lines that are ended by `\newline`: `1fil` left and `1fil` right by environment `center` and an the additional `1fil` via `\hfil` of `\newline` forces one third of the free space to the left and two third to the right.

Example with `\\`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,legalpaper]{report}

\usepackage[margin=.25in,text={8in,13.5in},centering]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
ARIZONA PRELIMINARY TWENTY DAY NOTICE \\
IN ACCORDANCE WITH ARIZONA REVISED STATUTES SECTION 33-992.01  \\
THIS IS NOT A LIEN AND IS NOT A REFLECTION ON THE INTEGRITY OF ANY
CONTRACTOR OR SUBCONTRACTOR
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]